# JNI Warning : Too many PopLocalFrame calls android

Tags: android, canvas, drawing, java-native-interface

I am developing an application and drawing SVG files, lines and images on canvas. and my issue is that when i save my diagram and re open it, it gives me the warning.

```
 JNI WARNING: too many PopLocalFrame calls.
```

does any body have any idea what is this warning says and how can i resolve it. i have goggled it around but have not got satisfactory thing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for calls to PushLocalFrame.  They should generally be paired.  Most likely you're calling PopLocalFrame without a preceding PushLocalFrame.

Generally you'll only call PushLocalFrame before calling into some Java code from JNI, and PopLocalFrame afterwards.  You don't have to, but it's a good way of cleaning up after the Java call if you've still got more native stuff to do.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. actually i am using svglib in my appication to draw svg diagrams. and i do not know about push or pop local frames. can you elaborate a bit or give me some link where they are explained in detail?

Comment: If you're not writing any JNI yourself then the issue is in svglib.  Push/PopLocalFrame are documented within the JNI docs (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html).

Comment: Can you suggest me something that how can i resolve this svglib issue?

Comment: Can you build svglib yourself?  If not, you'll not be able to do more than file a bug report with the svglib/adapter authors.  Calling PopLocalFrame without a matching push is not itself a problem, but it may indicate an issue with the programming logic.